# Автоматическое создание хардлинков по дубликатам

Tags: windows

Есть ли какие-нибудь программы, которые могли бы обшарить диск на дубликаты и для каждого из них создать хардлинки? В интернете нашел только программы, могущие удалить дубликаты и оставить ярлыки, но это, конечно, не то.

Comment: Я таких программ не знаю, но ведь самому написать — дело десяти минут, разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

[Duplicate Commander](http://rayburnsoft.net/dc.html)

Когда не получается что-то найти, напишите запрос по-английски. Обычно помогает.

```
windows duplicate to hardlink
```